# How to account for blank value in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to have excel notify me if its been 30 days after a certain date. The problem is if the date column is empty the Excel function is returning "No" (The false output in my logic test), instead of a blank.

This is the forumla I used.

```
=IF(R5<=30, "Yes", IF(R5>30, "No", IF(R5="", "")))
```

This is the forumla of the column it is pulling data from

```
=IF(F5="","",NETWORKDAYS(F5,TODAY()))
```

Is there any way to return "Yes", if the date is within 30 days, "No" if the date is greater than 30 days and a blank if there is no date?

Comment: Rearranging your logic should work. Try: `=IF(R5="","",IF(R5<=30,"YES","NO"))`. No need another `IF` since any other value will be greater than 30 anyway.

Comment: What's the value of R5? If it's a date, it's going to be much larger than 30.

Comment: @jsheeran I think it is a number, calculated from the other formula OP posted.

Comment: @jsheeran I am using networkdays() so it return the number of days in between two days not the actual date!

Comment: as @L42 said, rearranging will do the trick, have you tried rearranging them. Can you try that once. And let us know what happens